# UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash Image

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

Is it possible to retrieve the image that is displayed on the `UIBarButtonItem` when it's initialized with `UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash`?

Comment: You wanna download it or get it programmatically?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, though I would prefer programmatically

Comment: hope this will help you, [Link](http://archive.cnblogs.com/a/1882346/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I took the one from Apple and recreated it using Photoshop.